# delete existing users from database .NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, database

Im working this small project with NET MVC, I was able to add new user to my database and it shows in my UI nicely , somehow I cant not delete from the UI.I dont get any error so please help. thank in advance.

```
public JsonResult DeleteUser(string username)
{
    try
    {
        MyData.DB.Base.User.Delete(username);
        return new JsonResult() { Data = new { completed = true, username } };
    }
    catch
    {
        return new JsonResult() { Data = new { completed = false, username } };
    }
}
```

And here is my javascipt code:

```
User.UserRemoveFromUsers = function (username) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/User/DeleteUser', 
        type: "POST",
        data: "username=" + username,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.completed == true) {
                $('div.user[data=' + data.username + ']').remove();
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `data: "username=" + username,`

To : `data: { username : username },`

```
User.UserRemoveFromUsers = function (username) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/User/DeleteUser', 
        type: "POST",
        data: { username : username },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.completed == true) {
                $('div.user[data=' + data.username + ']').remove();
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. it still doesnt do anything for me.

Comment: Debug it and is fired `DeleteUser` method and what is the `username` value?